# Endless loop in a text menu when handling InputMismatchException

Tags: java, loops, exception, while-loop, switch-statement

I have a homework assignment to create a class with a looping menu to manage a queue of cars.  We learned queues in our last class.

My menu works perfectly fine until it catches `InputMismatchException` or `QueueEmptyException`, after which it goes into endless loop, not even stopping at the `userInput.nextInt();`.  It works when it catches `QueueFullException`, but not the others.

My code is:

```
import java.util.*;

public class CarQueueManagement {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InputMismatchException, QueueFullException{
        ArrayQueue queue = new ArrayQueue(3);;
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        int carNum;
        int choice = 0;

        queue.add(1);

        OUTER:
        while (true) {
            try{
                System.out.println("ΜΕΝΟΥ:\n\t1. Άφιξη αυτοκινήτου");
                System.out.println("\t2. Αναχώρηση αυτοκινήτου\n\t3. Κατάσταση ουράς\n\t4. Έξοδος");
                System.out.print("\n\tΕπιλογή (1-4): ");
                choice = userInput.nextInt();

                switch (choice){
                    case 1:
                        System.out.print("\n\tΆφιξη αυτοκινήτου:\n\t\tΑριθμός Αμαξιού");
                        carNum = userInput.nextInt();
                        queue.add(carNum);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        if(queue.isEmpty()){
                            System.out.println("\n\tΗ ουρά είναι άδεια, δεν χριάζεται διαγραφή.\n\n");
                            break;
                       }
                       String answer;
                        while(true){
                            System.out.print("\n\tΑναχώρηση αυτοκινήτου\n\t\tΕπιβεβαίωση; (y/n): ");
                            answer = userInput.next();
                            if(answer.equals("y")){
                                queue.remove();
                                break;
                            }
                            else if(answer.equals("n"))
                            break;
                        }
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        System.out.println("\n\tΚατάσταση ουράς:");
                        if(queue.isEmpty()) System.out.println("\t\tΗ ουρά είναι άδεια.\n\n");
                        else if(queue.isFull()) System.out.println("\t\tΗ ουρά είναι γεμάτη.\n\n");
                        else System.out.println("\t\tΗ ουρά έχει άδιες θέσοις.\n\n");
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        System.out.print("\n\nΕξοδος");
                        break OUTER;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }catch (InputMismatchException exc){
                System.out.println("\t\tΛΑΘΟΣ ΕΙΣΑΓΩΓΗ\n");  
            }catch(QueueEmptyException exc){
                System.out.println("\t\t" + exc.getMessage() + "\n");
            }catch(QueueFullException exc){
                System.out.println("\t\t" + exc.getMessage() + "\n");
            }
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: do you know what is `while (true)` doing?

Comment: i know that until i put a break; point it loops, but i also know that when i have a input code it needs to stop to take the input. It works with `QueueFullException` but not with the others. The other 2 exception are looping through everything without even stopping at the `userInput.nextInt();`

Comment: I bet you are pressing return key after entering a number?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java InputMismatchException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16816250/java-inputmismatchexception)

Comment: i press `Enter` i use NetBeans and i test my code with the implemented `Run` option, as you can tell i only want my code to exit the loop and terminate the program wih selection 4 witch say's 'Exit' in greek.

Comment: It’s seriously off-topic, but my Greek is so poor: is that άδιες or άδειες θέσοις?

Comment: it's "άδειες θέσεις" even i got it wrong on "θέσοις"

Comment: What did you enter to trigger the `QueueEmptyException` endless loop?  I was not able to reproduce the endless loop in Menu 2 (removing items from the queue), except by accident:  I entered `y` to remove an entry one time too many, so the `y` was fed to the main menu loop, triggering the `InputMismatchException` bug I described in my answer.  Is that what you did, or was it something different?

Comment: Any word on this?  Is there a way to reliably trigger that endless loop in Menu 2?  Any comment on my answer below?

Answer (score 2):

From the intro section of [`java.util.Scanner` docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) (emphasis mine):

> When a scanner throws an [`InputMismatchException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/InputMismatchException.html), **the scanner will not pass the token that caused the exception**, so that it may be retrieved or skipped via some other method.

Without the details, your `while(true)` loop is:

```
while (true) {
    try{
        choice = userInput.nextInt();
        switch (choice){
            case 1:
             ...
        }
    } catch (InputMismatchException exc){
        // Do nothing.
    }
}
```

When the user enters something that can't be converted to an integer, the `Scanner` throws an `InputMismatchException`, which you catch and ignore.  Then the `while` loop goes back to the top, where it tries to execute `userInput.nextInt()`...  but the `Scanner` is still looking at *the same invalid input*, so it immediately throws another `InputMismatchException`, which you catch and ignore again.  Execution continues at the top of the `while` loop, where it calls `nextInt()` again... and the cycle continues forever.

You have to force the `Scanner` to skip the bad input, so your `catch` block should look something like this:

```
}catch (InputMismatchException exc){
    System.out.println("\t\t[chastise the user in Greek]\n");  
    userInput.next();  // Skip invalid input.
}
```

### Other Advice

As a general rule, lots of small methods are easier to understand than one large method.  The nested `while` loops and `switch` statement were especially hard to follow.  I was only able to find the bug by breaking that gigantic `main` method into many smaller, private static methods.

At the very least, each menu item could be handled in its own method.  I also got rid of the `break` label by putting the whole menu into a separate method, which returned a `boolean` indicating whether the user was done or not.  That reduced the whole loop inside `main` to:

```
boolean done = false;
while (! done) {
    try{
        done = handleUserInput(queue, userInput);
    } catch (InputMismatchException exc) {
        System.out.println("\nINPUT ERROR\n");
        userInput.next();
    } // Other catch blocks as before...
}
```

My `handleUserInput` doesn't do much --- it gets user input, determines which method should handle that input, and then returns `true` or `false`...  It could be made simpler than this, too.

```
private static boolean handleUserInput(
  final ArrayQueue queue,
  final Scanner userInput
) {
    boolean done = false;
    printMenu();
    int choice = userInput.nextInt();
    switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            addToQueue(queue, userInput);
            break;
        case 2:
            removeFromQueue(queue, userInput);
            break;
        case 3:
            displayQueue(queue);
            break;
        case 4:
            printExitMessage();
            done = true;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return done;
}
```

Splitting the various menu activities into separate methods made them *much* easier to follow.  For example, when the logic was all mixed together in `main`, it was hard to tell if variables like `carNum` or `answer` were part of the problem.  In this version, `carNum` is a local variable trapped inside the `addToQueue` method, so when I'm working anywhere else, I can completely ignore it.